# Ruby Dates Calculation : Weird Outputs

Tags: ruby, date, syntax, whitespace

I have observed that a ruby expression calculating days difference gives different output dependent on the spaces in the expression.

```
Date.today             #=> #<Date: 2017-01-06 ((2457760j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
(Date.today - 60).to_s #=> "2016-11-07"
(Date.today-60).to_s   #=> "2016-11-07"
(Date.today- 60).to_s  #=> "2016-11-07"
(Date.today -60).to_s  #=> "2017-01-06" <- ???
```

Can anybody help me understand the reason behind it?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ seems to be a good question for an interview.

Answer (score 6):

That is the matter of operator precedence. [`Date::today`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today) accepts an optional argument.

```
Date.today - 60
```

is treated as

```
Date.today() - 60
```

while

```
(Date.today -60)
```

is treated as

```
Date.today(-60)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to mudasobwa's spot-on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41503662/477037): you should turn warnings on while developing.

Without `-w`:

```
$ ruby -rdate -e 'puts Date.today -60'
2017-01-06
```

With `-w`:

```
$ ruby -w -rdate -e 'puts Date.today -60'
-e:1: warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or a space even after `-' operator
-e:1: warning: invalid start is ignored
2017-01-06
```